# python socket function [] arguments

Tags: python, sockets

Code:

```
import socket
def get_protnumber(prefix):
  return dict( (getattr(socket, a), a)
    for a in dir(socket)
      if a.startswith(prefix))

proto_fam = get_protnumber('AF_')
types = get_protnumber('SOCK_')
protocols = get_protnumber('IPROTO_')

for res in socket.getaddrinfo('www.thapar.edu', 'http'):
  family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr = res

print 'Family         :', proto_fam[family]
print 'Type           :', types[socktype]
print 'Protocol       :', protocols[proto]
print 'Canonical name :', canonname
print 'Socket address :', sockaddr
```

Hello Its my first question sorry if there are some mitakes.

I didn't understand the function **get_protnumber**.where does **socket** and **a** come from .How this function takes arguments from sqauare brackets.like if i do this:

```
get_protnumber('AF_')[2]
```

it gives me **AF_INET**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where does **socket** and **a** come from?

**socket** is a module which is imported by `import socket`.
A module is also an object. Further more it's a global one so you can access it in function `get_protnumber`.

You can get an object's attributes by `dir(object)`. It will return a list of names of all its attributes. You can then iterate over the list by `for in` expression.
So `for a in dir(socket)` means iterate over socket's all attribute names.

The code below

```
return dict( (getattr(socket, a), a)
    for a in dir(socket)
      if a.startswith(prefix))
```

is equivalent to

```
return dict( (getattr(socket, a), a) for a in dir(socket) if a.startswith(prefix))
```

please notice the start and end of parentheses.

So `a` is some attribute name of socket object.

> how this function takes arguments from sqauare brackets?

No, it doesn's take argument from sqaurae brackets.

In `get_protnumber('AF_')[2]`, `'AF_'` is the argument and `[2]` means index the return value of function `get_protnumber` by `2`. In your case, get_protnumber return a dict, so you will get the value of key `2`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i understand it now but i still dont understand this line:(getattr(socket, a), a)

Comment: @Taimoor A good question. This makes a tuple of 2 elements. The first element is value of socket's attribute whose name is **a** and the second value is the attribute name **a**. Sorry I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: when i do **dir(socket)** it gives **
['AF_APPLETALK', 'AF_ASH', 'AF_ATMPVC', 'AF_ATMSVC', 'AF_AX25', 'AF_BLUETOOTH', 'AF_BRIDGE', 'AF_DECnet', 'AF_ECONET', 'AF_INET', 'AF_INET6', 'AF_IPX', 'AF_IRDA', 'AF_KEY', 'AF_LLC', 'AF_NETBEUI', 'AF_NETLINK', 'AF_NETROM', 'AF_PACKET', 'AF_PPPOX', 'AF_ROSE', 'AF_ROUTE', 'AF_SECURITY', 'AF_SNA', 'AF_TIPC', 'AF_UNIX', 'AF_UNSPEC', 'AF_WANPIPE', 'AF_X25'].Here index of AF_INET is 10 but in the function its 2 how?Sorry for asking too much questions.I am new to programming

Comment: The function returns a dictionary not an array. The key for AF_INET in the dict is attribute value of socket object which in your case is 2.